# Fast semi-join in list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, list, performance, merge

I am trying to perform a semi-join on a list of data frames. I have about 1000 data frames of 50,000 rows, on which I want to select a subset of rows depending on another data frame.

Consider this example:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = 50:150)
set.seed(1)
l <- replicate(1000,
                 data.frame(id = sample(1:100, 50000, replace = TRUE),
                  id2 = sample(letters, 50000, replace = TRUE),
                  info = runif(50000, 200, 300)),
                 simplify = FALSE)
```

I want to subset each data frame of `l` depending on the ids of `df1`. I can do that by performing a semi-join, or subsetting with `%in%`:

```r
library(dplyr)
semi_join(l[[1]], df1, "id")

l[[1]][l[[1]]$id %in% df1$id, ]
```

I'm looking for a fast solution that scales to thousands of data frames. so far, I wrap this in `lapply` (but there might be faster, vectorized solutions).

```r
lapply(l, \(x) semi_join(x, df1, "id"))
```

Here's a starting benchmark with the solutions:

```r
bc <- bench::mark(lapply(l, \(x) semi_join(x, df1, "id")),
            lapply(l, \(x) x[x$id %in% df1$id, ]), iterations = 1, check = FALSE)

> bc
# A tibble: 2 × 13
#  expression                                            min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr
#  <bch:expr>                                       <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int>
#1 lapply(l, function(x) semi_join(x, df1, "id"))    9.34s   9.34s  0.107   1.97GB   0.428     1
#2 lapply(l, function(x) x[x$id %in% df1$id, ])     14.19s  14.19s  0.0705   2.5GB   0.282     1
```

Comment: Did you try  a `data.table` approach?

Comment: I'm open for `data.table` options, not sure how to optimize

Comment: I m not sure either but I think convert your dataframes to data.tables `l <- lapply(l, as.data.table)` and then something like `lapply(l, \(i) i[df1, on = "id", nomatch = NULL])`? Maybe `setkey()` here can improve it

Comment: 1000 data frames sounds like this should be a single data frame, you might `bind_rows(,.id = "source")` then semi join on the full table, then split if you really have to

Comment: @Maël Can you expand on your desire for speed? Do you have a single set of ~1,000 `data.frame`s that you will need to do multiple subsets on, or is it a single subset on each of different sets of ~1,000 `data.frame`s? If you are building the data set, it would be better to build a single large `data.table` with an id column and do a single subset. If you are doing multiple subsets on a single set of `data.frame`s, it would be better to `rbindlist` them first.

Comment: I have ~1,000 dataframes of unequal length (`l`) on which I need to perform the semi-join. The result is to create another ~1,000 dataframes that are all subset of `df1`.  I realize my example was a bit clumsy since it created subset of `l`,  and not of `df1`.

Comment: I'll open a new question with a more precise example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Thanks for the comment from @jblood94, we have another more efficient argument rather than using `rep` to add `grp` column, and it does improve the performance (see `dtsplit1`)

```
microbenchmark(
  "dtsplit1" = split(rbindlist(l, idcol = "grp"), by = "grp", keep.by = FALSE),
  "dtsplit" = split(rbindlist(l)[, grp := rep(seq_along(l), each = 50000)], by = "grp", keep.by = FALSE),
  times = 10
)
```

gives

```
Unit: seconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 dtsplit1 1.779087 1.843032 1.989136 1.957378 2.041067 2.391234    10
  dtsplit 2.059481 2.150111 2.190301 2.176397 2.215940 2.387897    10
```

---

If you have fixed `50000` rows for all of your  "real" 1000 dataframes, hopefully the following code can help a bit

```
library(data.table)
split(rbindlist(l)[, grp := rep(seq_along(l), each = 50000)], by = "grp", keep.by = FALSE)
```

## Benchmark

```
microbenchmark(
  "semijoin" = lapply(l, \(x) semi_join(x, df1, "id")),
  "in" = lapply(l, \(x) x[x$id %in% df1$id, ]),
  "dtsplit" = split(rbindlist(l)[, grp := rep(seq_along(l), each = 50000)], by = "grp", keep.by = FALSE),
  times = 10
)
```

shows

```
Unit: seconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 semijoin 2.679046 3.122411 3.589847 3.375409 3.544307 5.084460    10
       in 4.357969 4.789931 6.271855 6.207127 7.651371 8.430053    10
  dtsplit 1.680729 2.685881 3.377203 2.922039 3.239485 7.833068    10
```

Comment: The `idcol` argument of `rbindlist` is useful here: `split(rbindlist(l, idcol = "grp"), by = "grp", keep.by = FALSE)`. It's also ~30% faster.

Comment: @jblood94 aha, what an adorable argument that I should not miss it! Thank you very much for such a helpful reminder!

Comment: Thanks! great answer. I realize this is slightly not what I wanted (not the same amount of rows, and the subset should be done on df1, but that's my bad!), but this plainly answers my original question, hence the accept.

Comment: @Maël You can try my update, the argument `idcol` should apply to non-identical number of rows for all dataframes.